# Internet not working arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, internet-connection

I have been experiencing quite some problems with internet connection. Sometimes it works for a long time but when I started my computer today it didn't work again while I have no problems with my phone and rebooting didn't help (it did a few times). I read the wiki articles about network but I couldn't find anything. As I'm not very experienced with Linux I don't really know what to do next. So here are some things that might be useful:

I am connected via ethernet but if it could be fixed for WiFi as well that would be great. I run the normal arch. WiFi isn't working and ethernet used to just work by plugging in but doesn't anymore.

output from lspci https://pastebin.com/LrLueZkB

I cannot ping archlinux.org

Default route seems to be set although I cannot ping it

Output IP link https://pastebin.com/xap7Q8mB

I have network manager, dhclient and ufw installed. Dhcpcd is running
Iptables https://pastebin.com/B0VYMF1B
Ip a l
https://pastebin.com/Sb893BDT

Ip r l
https://pastebin.com/mqMx9BXC

Ps auwx
https://pastebin.com/EZ8w6dkF

Comment: Would you please post output from following commands: 'sudo iptables -L -v', 'ip a l', 'ip r l', 'ps auwx'.

Comment: I added the info

Comment: It looks to me that your iptables rules DROP nearly every input packets. I do not see lines accepting RELATED,ESTABLISHED packets. Even your rules allows output packets, it looks their responses are dropped. Would you please try manually disable your IPTABLES rules by 'sudo iptables -F' and then try 'ping 192.168.2.254', 'ping 8.8.8.8' and 'telnet 8.8.8.8 53'. Please note the 'iptables -F' will effectively disable packet filtering on your system until next ufw restart.